# Chatting module textarea input

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the following chat module, I am not able to understand how to add a Jquery command for making the inputed message displayed in the chat body when the enter key is pressed.i want the message to be displayed in msg_b format.I tried out the following command but it did not work:

```
$('textarea').keypress(
function(e){
if(e.keyCode==13){
var msg=$(this).val();
$this.val(");
$("<div class='msg_b'>"+msg+"</div>").insertBefore('.msg_insert');
}
});
});
```

and here is a part of my html script:

```
<div class="msg_head">Rishabh Sood
<div class="close"> x </div>
</div>

<div class ="msg_wrap">
<div class ="msg_body">
<div class ="msg_a">Hey bro wassup!</div>
<div class ="msg_b">All nice!</div>
<div class="msg_insert"></div>
</div>

<div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4" placeholder ="Enter Message"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html code should be like:

```
<body>
<div class="msg_head">Rishabh Sood
  <div class="close"> x </div>
</div>
<div class="msg_wrap">
  <div class="msg_body">
    <div class="msg_a">Hey bro wassup!</div>
    <div class="msg_b">All nice!</div>
    <div class="msg_insert"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="msg_footer">
    <textarea id="commentTxt" class="msg_input" rows="4" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
```

and script.js file will be like:

```
        $('#commentTxt').keypress(
        function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
        var msg=$(this).val();
        $("<div class='msg_b'>"+msg+"</div>").insertBefore('.msg_insert');
        }
        });
```

You can check this on [Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JhnAzGQuE5kZn5ploAcm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I got that correct now. But,can you please tell me how to add a refresh code through Jquery, such that when I click it, all my input messages get erased?

Comment: Simply declare  a parent div tag before the messages tabs and write a  Button click and in button click write that div html as null ex: <div class="parentDiv"><div>. And in jquey $('#parentdiv').html('');